# Paytm Payment Integration in Django

Tags: django, paytm

I am facing a weird issue with Paytm Payment Integration in Django3. While the successful transaction flow is smooth. Failure cases are sending GET parameters to my django application like this on the callback URL:

retryAllowed=false&errorMessage=Your%20payment%20has%20been%20declined%20by%20your%20bank.%20Please%20try%20again%20or%20use%20a%20different%20method%20to%20complete%20the%20payment.&errorCode=227

And this seems particular to Net Banking gateways.

Some help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Paytm sends the response on the callback URL with query string in case of failed transaction. You can connect to paytm in case any problem to handle this.